# Insert ascending numbering in photos of a folder with imagemagick

Tags: image, numbers, imagemagick

Which command line or script to use to insert ascending numbering on photos in a folder with imagemagick.

I've tried several lines and scripts, but without getting the expected result. The best I could do was insert the same number in all the photos.

Comment: Do you mean you want some existing files renamed with numbers? Or you want to create some numbered files? Or you want to add annotations including numbers onto existing images? You didn't state your OS.

Comment: Write the numbers in ascending order inside the pictures themselves.

Comment: And your operating system?

Comment: Operating system is Ubuntu.

Comment: Note that for future questions, you should provide a [mcve] of your own efforts and proper examples of what sort of input images you have and how you are trying to make the resulting output images appear. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

N=1
for f in *.jpg; do
   # Generate the annotation text in whatever format is desired
   annotation=$(printf "Image: %03d" $N)
   # Decide name of output file - in our case it is the same as input but prepended with "annotated-"
   out="annotated-$f"
   magick "$f" -fill white -undercolor '#00000080' -gravity South \
     -pointsize 24 -annotate +0+5 "$annotation" "$out"
   ((N=N+1))
done
```

And it will annotate all JPEG images like this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, I made some changes to the script to suit what I want to do, so it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

    N=1
    for f in *.jpg; do
       # Generate the annotation text in whatever format is desired
       annotation=$(printf "%01d" $N)
       # Decide name of output file - in our case it is the same as input but prepended with "annotated-"
       out="out/$f"
       convert "$f" -fill black -gravity northwest \
         -pointsize 50 -annotate +200+330 "$annotation" "$out"
       ((N=N+1))
    done
```

However, all the photos came out with the number "1" written, and I expected the number "1" to come out in the first photo, the number "2" in the second photo, and always the numbering increasing with each photo. What error could there be in the script, I had already tried with others, but I got the same result.

Comment: This should be edited into your question really, because if it doesn't work it isn't an answer. Anyway, you can debug your script by running it with `-xv` flags. So, if your script is called `annotater.sh`, start it with `bash -xv ./annotator.sh` and you should see all the lines as they are executed and hopefully spot the problem. If not, click [edit] and paste in the debug messages from a dummy directory with just 2-3 images.

Comment: You can also paste the script into https://shellcheck.net for suggestions.